# How to count deep relationship fields with Django?

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework

How could I count the relationship of the models below?

```py
class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)

class Pet(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, related_name='pet')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)         

class Photo(models.Model):
    pet = models.ForeignKey(Pet, related_name='photo')
    photo = models.ImageField(storage=DIR)
```

I would like to return the total pet and total photos taken of all pets dr to a single customer client, with the following answer:

```json
[
    {
        "name": "john",
        "totalPet": 3, // imagine 10 photos were taken of each pet
        "totalPhoto": 30,
    },
    {
        "name": "Mary",
        "totalPet": 2, // imagine that 10 photos were taken of one and 5 
                      //  of another pet
        "totalPhoto": 15,
    },
]
```

My serializer is as follows:

```py
class ClientSerializer(ModelSerializer):  
    totalPet = serializers.SerializerMethodField()     

    def get_totalPet(self, obj):       
        return obj.pet.count()

    class Meta:
        model = Client     
        fields = ('name', 'totalPet')
```

As can be observed, I can total the amount of pets for each customer, but I can't find a way to total the photos of all pets of a customer.

What would be the best way to do this photo count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform a filter on `Photo` model with your `client.pet` queryset, using the [`__in`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#in) lookup.

---

At first, I would define a [custom `QuerySet`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/managers/#calling-custom-queryset-methods-from-the-manager) for our `Photo` model:

```py
from django.db import models


class PhotoQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def for_client(self, client):
        # Get all related pets to the current client
        client_pets = client.pet.all()

        # Filter Photos that are linked with these pets
        return self.filter(pet__in=client_pets)
```

And then inside the model:

```py
class Photo(models.Model):
    ...

    objects = PhotoQuerySet.as_manager()
```

This will allow you to do the following: `Photo.objects.for_client(client=...)`

---

After that, you can use this method in the serializer:

```py
class ClientSerializer(ModelSerializer):  
    total_pets = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    total_photos = serializers.SerializerMethodField()    

    def get_total_pets(self, obj):       
        return obj.pet.count()

    def get_total_photos(self, obj):
        # Calling our newly created method and aggregating count
        return Photo.objects.for_client(client=obj).count()

    class Meta:
        model = Client     
        fields = ('name', 'total_pets', 'total_photos')
```

Comment: It worked like a charm! I am a week looking for a solution on the internet and saw nothing about it that could solve. Am I modeling my database schema correctly? Surprised that I didn't find anything similar to what you posted. Thank you very much.